# RestKit map an Array containing lat & lng to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have data being passed over from a RestAPI that has an array field called location, which contains a lat & lng.

I wondering what is the best way to store this in CoreData, as a CLLocation, the raw lat/lng as doubles, or a transformable? Besides how to store it, how do I map it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the lat/long is being passed as an array, doesn't sound like a well designed API. If it is an array then the easiest thing to do is store it as transformable and provide a custom method on the object to return a `CLCoordinate2D`. The disadvantage of this is that you won't be able to write predicates to search based on location. If you want to search by location you would want to store the raw lat/long values as doubles, but it sounds like mapping this could be difficult.